# PHP sessions or cookies not storing on server. PHP.ini misconfiguration

Tags: session, cookies, php

I am working on a simple SESSION/COOKIE login system for a website on a standard shared hosting account. The problem is that neither sessions or cookies are stored. My code is 100% correct but the server is misconfigured.

I have noticed that there was no folder in which to store sessions so I created one and added a local php.ini file. Sessions are stored in that folder properly but they don't work when I try to use them in my PHP website.

I have talked to support but they are very bad.

The server configuration is this: http://luttnerre.com/test.php

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions on the specified directory? The php process needs to be able to write to it.

Comment: Thank you for replying ! Which are your recommended permissions ? And yes, it has write permissions. I told you that session files were created. I also checked the information in those session files and it is OK.

Comment: @user927901 Sorry, I must have misread the part where session files were being created. If the files are there, then there's no problem regarding permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If cookies aren't being stored on client browsers then something is wrong with your code, these don't depend on the server session handling being configured correctly.  If cookies aren't being stored, then sessions won't either so I'd look at the cookie problem first, then the session one.

Comment: Well, I use setcookie('test','test',100000); to create a cookie and session_start(); before setting session variables. That's not the problem. I also created single PHP files which tried to store a single session or cookie variable but it didn't work either...

Comment: well, you're the one that said "The problem is that neither sessions or cookies are stored."...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that cookies and session variables must be declared before any other output or you have to turn output buffering on. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Even empty characters in a include before or after  tags can lead to errors.

Also check your error_reporting level since some important debug messages could stay supressed. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php