# Cookie doesnt set after login

Tags: php, cookies

Does someone know why this cookie doesn't wanna work, I been trying a lot of different things but it doesn't wanna make a cookie at all.

**Script I'am using**:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM plattegrond_gebruikers WHERE email = '$username' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());;
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
// User found, now let's create the cookies for the user!
if(!$_COOKIE["userid"]) {
    setcookie("userid",$row["id"],time()+3600,'/','nieuws.holapress.com');

    if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){
        $cookieSet = 'The cookie is ' . $_COOKIE['userid'];
        } else {
        $cookieSet = 'No cookie has been set';
        }

        echo $cookieSet;
}else{
    echo"cookie excists";
}
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Everything works like it should, it makes the query, it gets the users information but it just doesn't set a cookie, and after login I get the "No cookie has been set". does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You will get set cookie on next refresh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem setting/checking cookie in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409575/problem-setting-checking-cookie-in-php)

Comment: after a refresh it still says there is no cookie

Answer (score 2):

Probably you checking on local machine with parameter `nieuws.holapress.com`. Change it to your localhost.

Comment: Or just don't pass that parameter.

Comment: @Rikesh yes, it's better in this case.

Comment: if i completly take the parameter out it  still doesnt set the cookie

Comment: maybe you have white spaces before `setcookie` check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8895429/739897

Answer (score 0):

The cookie can be read after reloading the page, because the first time you set the cookie, it will be send to browser, the browser will save it, then, for next requests, the browser include the cookie, and the server can read it.

Comment: if i refresh it will still say there is no cookie.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put in 1 line: session_start(); In all pages

Comment: What is relation of session when he is trying to set cookie ?